# How possible send notification with using curl command, without file in Kaa?

Tags: curl, kaa

I want send notification **without file in the curl** command.

And then, this is my curl command with file :

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -X POST --header 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data' -F'notification={"applicationId":"3","schemaId":"65564","topicId":"2","type":"USER"};type=application/json' --header 'Accept:application/json' 'http://192.168.10.49:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification' -F file=@notification.json
```

How possible send notification without using the file *(with message body in curl command ?!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
echo '{ ...your notification... }' | curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -X POST --header 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data' -F'notification={"applicationId":"3","schemaId":"65564","topicId":"2","type":"USER"};type=application/json' --header 'Accept:application/json' 'http://192.168.10.49:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification' -F file=@-
```

`@-` instructs curl to read data from stdin.

This answer is adapted from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77588/passing-binary-data-to-curl-without-using-a-file).